# LiveData in Android App (race condition?)

Tags: android

These are some general questions with respect to LiveData in Android.

1. Is it advisable to create UI objects based on LiveData?
2. If yes, and I have the UI object state depend on another piece of LiveData, don't I automatically create a race condition?

Alternatively stated, how do I ensure that the state is updated based on LiveData value, if the objects are dynamically created based on an observer of different LiveData? As far as I understand I can not simply read the LiveData state information during creation of the objects.

Comment: "Is it advisable to create UI objects based on LiveData?" -- you might consider editing your question and providing a *lot* more detail on what "create UI objects" means. "I have the UI object state depend on another piece of LiveData, don't I automatically create a race condition?" -- strictly speaking, no, as you always observe a `LiveData` on the main application thread.

Comment: "how do I ensure that the state is updated based on LiveData value, if the objects are dynamically created based on an observer of different LiveData?" -- in this case, having two independent-but-not-really-independent `LiveData` may be a problem. However, that's not a limitation of `LiveData`, as you would have similar issues with other reactive solutions (e.g., RxJava `Observable`, Kotlin `Flow`).

Comment: To clarify, I am creating buttons based on the number of objects present in the first LiveData interface. The second LiveData object contains which button is pressed. Thus if the buttons are created after the observers are set, the buttons don't get updated.

Comment: "I am creating buttons based on the number of objects present in the first LiveData interface" -- FWIW, I would go far out of my way to avoid writing apps this way, at least when working with the `View` system. Jetpack Compose is more amenable to that approach, and even there the solution would be to have a single `LiveData` (or, more likely, `MutableState`) that describes the whole UI state, rather than two independent-but-not-really-independent sources of truth.

Comment: Thanks, I think I agree there is no clean solution to this.